Is there a git merge strategy which can resolve next merge conflict?
TLDR;

On master branch the discourse section was removed
On dev branch the fddkim section was removed
dev branch is being rebased on top of master
A merge conflict happened

I am looking for an option which can do the next in this situation:

See from diff between 'HEAD' and 'parent' that discourse section was deleted.
Apply this removal to >>>>>>> 50fc8707
If no conflicts occurs for previous step, resolve merge conflict automatically
or, at least, ask interactively to confirm suggested resolution with simple yes/no.

Is there a git option for a such strategy to resolve merge conflict automatically?

My apologies for a long post details, but merge conflicts were never simple.
git diff for this situation it is pretty unreadable and wrong:

Git tells that the next lines was removed
-resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-files_CNAME"
-name    = "files.xxx.com."
-ghs.googlehosted.com.
Git readds those lines after >>>>>>>>

git version 2.43.0


We can see that files section was untouched, if the file is opened in an editor:
resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-calendar_CNAME" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.xxx.zone_id
  name    = "calendar.xxx.com."
  type    = "CNAME"
  records = [
    "ghs.googlehosted.com.",
  ]
  ttl     = 3600
}

<<<<<<< HEAD
resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-fddkim_CNAME" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.xxx.zone_id
  name    = "fddkim.xxx.com."
  type    = "CNAME"
  records = [
    "spfmx.domainkey.freshdesk.com.",
  ]
  ttl     = 3600
}

||||||| parent of 50fc8707 (Removed DNS RRs which authorized FreshDesk to send emails on our behalf)
resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-discourse_A" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.xxx.zone_id
  name    = "discourse.xxx.com."
  type    = "A"
  records = [
    "1.2.3.4",
  ]
  ttl     = 3600
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-fddkim_CNAME" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.xxx.zone_id
  name    = "fddkim.xxx.com."
  type    = "CNAME"
  records = [
    "spfmx.domainkey.freshdesk.com.",
  ]
  ttl     = 3600
}

=======
resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-discourse_A" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.xxx.zone_id
  name    = "discourse.xxx.com."
  type    = "A"
  records = [
    "1.2.3.4",
  ]
  ttl     = 3600
}

>>>>>>> 50fc8707 (Removed DNS RRs which authorized FreshDesk to send emails on our behalf)
resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-files_CNAME" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.xxx.zone_id
  name    = "files.xxx."
  type    = "CNAME"
  records = [
    "ghs.googlehosted.com.",
  ]
  ttl     = 3600
}

From the diff above we can see that:

the section for files subdomain was not touched at all.
the section discourse was removed in master branch
the parent has both discourse and fddkim sections
the section fddkim was removed in dev branch

Here the diffs for removals:
@@ -299,16 +299,6 @@ resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-cal>
   ttl     = 3600
 }

-resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-discourse_A" {
-  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.xxx.zone_id
-  name    = "discourse.xxx.com."
-  type    = "A"
-  records = [
-    "45.55.79.151",
-  ]
-  ttl     = 3600
-}
-
 resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-fddkim_CNAME" {
   zone_id = aws_route53_zone.xxx.zone_id
   name    = "fddkim.xxx.com."

@@ -309,16 +277,6 @@ resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-dis>
   ttl     = 3600
 }

-resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-fddkim_CNAME" {
-  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.xxx.zone_id
-  name    = "fddkim.xxx.com."
-  type    = "CNAME"
-  records = [
-    "spfmx.domainkey.freshdesk.com.",
-  ]
-  ttl     = 3600
-}
-
 resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-files_CNAME" {
   zone_id = aws_route53_zone.xxx.zone_id
   name    = "files.xxx.com."


PS. It would be nice to know the option which will instruct git to do section groping, instead of line-by-line (yeah, I know, some lines are duplicated, but it is easier to read/understand the output):
@@@ -299,16 -267,16 +267,6 @@@ resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx>
    ttl     = 3600
  }

- resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-fddkim_CNAME" {
--  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.xxx.zone_id
-   name    = "fddkim.xxx.com."
-   type    = "CNAME"
--  records = [
-     "spfmx.domainkey.freshdesk.com.",
--  ]
--  ttl     = 3600
--}
--
---VS
 -resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-discourse_A" {
--  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.xxx.zone_id
 -  name    = "discourse.xxx.com."
 -  type    = "A"
--  records = [
 -    "1.2.3.4",
--  ]
--  ttl     = 3600
--}
--
  resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-files_CNAME" {
    zone_id = aws_route53_zone.xxx.zone_id
    name    = "files.xxx.com."

Instead of this:
@@@ -299,16 -267,16 +267,6 @@@ resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx>
    ttl     = 3600
  }

- resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-fddkim_CNAME" {
 -resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-discourse_A" {
--  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.xxx.zone_id
-   name    = "fddkim.xxx.com."
-   type    = "CNAME"
 -  name    = "discourse.xxx.com."
 -  type    = "A"
--  records = [
-     "spfmx.domainkey.freshdesk.com.",
 -    "1.2.3.4",
--  ]
--  ttl     = 3600
--}
--
  resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-files_CNAME" {
    zone_id = aws_route53_zone.xxx.zone_id
    name    = "files.xxx.com."


Have you tried some different merge strategies? I have some clarifying questions. 1) "git diff for this situation it is pretty unreadable and wrong" What command did you run? 2) Do you have any diff or merge options in your config? 3) "Here the diffs for removals:" Which diff is which branch? 4) "the option which will instruct git to do section groping" I don't think there is any such option, that would require Git to parse the text. 5) "We can see that files section was untouched" What is the files section?

"the option which will instruct git to do section groping" The closest thing I can think of is --function-context. You may need to define a custom hunk header.

@Schwern 1) This is just simple git diff <conflict-file-name>; 2) Here is my whole ~/.gitconfig https://perl.bot/p/6wj4qs; 3) Lets start from ||||||| parent. Here you can see both discourse and fddkim sections as they were before changes. discourse section was deleted on master branch. You do not see this in <<<< HEAD block. fddkim section was removed on dev branch. You do not see it in >>>>> 50fc block. 4) Ok; 5) files section is the resource "aws_route53_record" "xxx-files_CNAME" section you see after >>>>> 50fc block.

Probably it would be more correct if I call section as the resource block for files, discourse and fddkim subdomains.
